# onkeypress Email Validation using ajax js and php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation, email

Preface: this will eventually expand to a signup sheet, but I am more concerned with getting one portion completed first.

Now you will not be able to connect to my server, but I do need help, or at least an explanation of why this code isn't working. I have been working on this for a week or so, and have found nothing really similar to my problem.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="checking.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="conTest">
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("L28-6","turkey","supersecretpassword","stored");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
                echo"Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            } else {
                echo "success";
            }
        ?>
        </span>
        Email: <input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="emailCheck(this.value)"/>
        <br/>
        <span id="emailError"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main error is somewhere in the js which looks like:

```
function emailCheck(inputvalue) 
{    
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
    var span=document.getElementById("emailError");
    if(pattern.test(inputvalue))
    {         
        span.innerHTML="true..checking";    
        var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var response = myRequest.reponseText;
        myRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200)
            {
                if(response.test(inputvalue))
                {
                    span.innerHTML="already in use";
                }
                else
                {
                    span.innerHTML="valid";
                }
            }

            myRequest.open("POST", "email.php", true);
            myRequest.send();
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        span.innerHTML="not valid email"; 
    }
}
```

The problem is definitely with the ajax call but here is the php portion (which isn't in working condition yet):

```
<?php
mysqli_query($con,"select user_email from email");
?>
```

I know its a lot of code, but I really appreciate any input. 
Also here is the page's response when a properly formed email is used:

Email:asdfasdf@yahoo.com
true..checking

so I know for certain it isn't even dropping into the myRequest.readystatechange function, because if it where it should, at least, return "not valid email".

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is inside the readystatechange. This means the ajax request will never be called.

try something like :

```
function emailCheck(inputvalue) 
{   
var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
var span=document.getElementById("emailError");
if(pattern.test(inputvalue))
{         
    span.innerHTML="true..checking";    
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = myRequest.reponseText;
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200)
        {
            if(response.test(inputvalue))
            {
            span.innerHTML="already in use";
            }
            else
            {
            span.innerHTML="valid";
            }
        }

    }
    myRequest.open("POST", "email.php", true);
    myRequest.send();
}
else
{   
    span.innerHTML="not valid email"; 
}
}
```

I can see another issue with your code. The email will be valid even before finish to be filled

something@domain.c will be valid even if i need to informe something@domain.com. Use a button to request the validation

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I've created a separate function for the ajax portion, and created an 'if matches pattern show validate button'. As for the problem with matching:I was going to use a different validation checking technique, but the box I am using is restricted to my school network (so I can't access the internet) and therefore found the regex stuff most useful.

Thanks again